# Monokai Theme for multiple IDE's

Tags: themes

Does anyone know of a good source for finding themes for multiple IDE's, I'm specifically looking for a good Monokai version to use but wouldn't mind others that have a darker background. I use Android Studio (which is based off IntelliJ), Visual Studio 2013, and Xcode for mobile development as well as TextWrangler and Navicat for other work and like to use themes that are similar within each IDE. I did find one Repo on GitHub [Base16 Theme](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16) but I'm trying to find more themes or builders like this that can spit out the same theme for various IDE's that I use for development.

Answer (score 1):

- Vim: https://github.com/tomasr/molokai
- Xcode https://github.com/b0ti/xcode-monokai-revisited
- emacs: https://github.com/oneKelvinSmith/monokai-emacs

All you need to do is:  [search on github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=monokai)

Answer (score 0):

Someone has created a version of the theme for Android Studio.
Full instructions on installing it [here](http://envyandroid.com/archives/1000/monokai-theme-in-android-studio-and-intellij)